# Compression not working with imagepng

Tags: php, optimization, png

I have a simple function which download an image from an url address ($filein), store it locally on the server and after apply a compression based on the quality level of the imagepng function like that :

```
function create_img_memoire($REF,$filein)
{
    //get file and store it
    $fileout = '/home/images/public_html/memoire/'.$REF.'.png'; 
    file_put_contents($fileout, file_get_contents($filein));

    //compress it
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($fileout);
    imagepng($im, $fileout, 9);
}
```

The file is downloaded but the compression doesn't work. So the first part of the function is well but the second part isn't working meaning the compression.

Comment: ...and...? What is happening or not happening?

Comment: Sorry I edit the question...

Comment: I don't smell any compression here. O.o

Comment: Yep you're right, but imagepng should compress the $im file no?

Comment: How do you assert that "the compression isn't working"? What do you expect to happen and what doesn't happen?

Comment: I play with the quality of imagepng and 0 or 9 provide the same file size...

Comment: I don't think that's the right way.. You should be looking here actually http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecompressionquality.php

Comment: Have you tried writing to a *different* file and compare the results?

Comment: I try with differents files and you're right, imagecreatefrompng and Imagepng doesn't work... I should miss something somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution of this problem. I download a .jpg file and name it .png so the mime type wasn't PNG but JPG! I need to use imagecreatefromjpeg instead of imagecreatefromfunction

```
create_img_memoire($REF,$filein)

    {
        //get file and store it
        $fileout = '/home/images/public_html/memoire/'.$REF.'.jpg'; 
        file_put_contents($fileout, file_get_contents($filein));

        //compress it
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileout);

        $fileout2 = '/home/images/public_html/memoire/'.$REF.'-op9.png'; 
        imagepng($im, $fileout2, 9);
        $fileout3 = '/home/images/public_html/memoire/'.$REF.'-op5.png'; 
        imagepng($im, $fileout3, 5);
        $fileout4 = '/home/images/public_html/memoire/'.$REF.'-op0.png'; 
        imagepng($im, $fileout4, 0);
    }
```